# Find all (including overlapping) substrings matching a regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex, performance

I need to find positions of all substrings matching a regular expression within a string. For instance, if the string is `abbba` and the regexp is `(b|bb)(?=a)`, the result should be `[(2, 4), (3, 4)]`.

What I’ve come up with is

```py
def get_ranges(pattern: str, string: str) -> list[tuple[int, int]]:
    n = len(string)
    return [(start, end) for start in range(n + 1) for end in range(start, n + 1)
            if re.fullmatch(f'.{{{start}}}({pattern}).{{{n - end}}}', string)]
```

But this tends to perform extremely slowly, especially given that it doesn’t allow precompiled regexps to be used. Are there any more efficient ways to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

First of all I think you should use `for end in range(start, n + 1)`. For the `end` variable I don't see any reason to start ranging from 0 for every iteration. Just with this edit, executing this code

```
for i in range(300000):
    get_ranges(r"(b|bb)(?=a)", "abbba")
```

I pass from 9.67 to 6.01 secs.

Comment: Nice catch, thank you. I’ve updated my original code. I don’t think, however, that this resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a slightly different regex - `(b{1,2})(?=a)` which should be slightly faster.

Secondly, you can compile the pattern and use it compiled by cutting the string and not the regex:

```
pattern = re.compile('(b{1,2})(?=a)')
def get_ranges(pattern: str, string: str):

result = []
start, end = 0, len(string)
match = pattern.search(string)
while match is not None and start < end:
    result.append((match.start(0)+start, match.end(0)+start))
    start += match.start(0) + 1
    match = pattern.search(string[start:])

return result
```

You can also `yield` instead of constructing `result` in its entirety before returning.

Timings for comparison (per 1 million execs):

- original: 38.42 s
- above: 2.14 s (17.95x speedup)
- `yield` version: 0.2914 s (131.85x speedup)

Comment: Unfortunately, this will not work in the general case, since multiple matching substrings can start at a single location. Moreover, removing prefix of the string will interfere with lookbehinds (which I do need to use as well). So, for example, the pattern `(?<=a)(b{1,2})` will produce `[(1, 3)]` instead of the expected `[(1, 2), (1, 3)]`, and there doesn’t seem to be a quick fix for it.

Comment: Well, you did not specify this in the question, did you? But if you need lookbehinds then indeed it is not going to work in your case.

Comment: This seems to be equivalent to just `return [m.span(1) for m in re.finditer(f'(?=({pattern}))', string)]`

Comment: @sophros This is not just about lookbehinds. Simple `b{1,2}`, with the string `bb` being matched against it, will return `[(0, 2), (1, 2)]` and not `[(0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]` as would be expected.

Comment: Agreed. The solution is suboptimal for regexes with optional greedy matches.